Flutter App: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on DexPathList
A while ago, I updated android studio and since then, my android emulators have not been letting me test the app. I have not attempted to test the app on a physical android device, since I do not have one. It works perfectly on apple simulated and real devices.
When attempting to run my app on an android emulator, the app opens and immediately closes. When looking at logcat, I found this error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thehyvehouse.hyveapp/com.thehyevhouse.hyveapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.thehyevhouse.hyveapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~vu-gOLiBCgxn3KhIjRCA4g==/com.thehyvehouse.hyveapp-DnARGrxW7tAQatL3A0pJvA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~vu-gOLiBCgxn3KhIjRCA4g==/com.thehyvehouse.hyveapp-DnARGrxW7tAQatL3A0pJvA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~vu-gOLiBCgxn3KhIjRCA4g==/com.thehyvehouse.hyveapp-DnARGrxW7tAQatL3A0pJvA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]


I have been updating my MainActivity and other files according to other posts I have found with similar issues, but cannot seem to get it to work. To give more input, my MainActivity is a .kt file and is under the kotlin folder in android/app/src/main NOT the java folder (not sure if this is the reason?)
My flutter doctor has no issues.
Here is my MainActivity.kt file:
package com.thehyvehouse.hyveapp

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}


Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thehyvehouse.hyveapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:label="Hyve"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            tools:targetApi="honeycomb">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


Here is my app level build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.thehyevhouse.hyveapp"
    compileSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.compileSdkVersion, 33)
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thehyvehouse.hyveapp"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
//    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
//   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}


Here is my android level build.gradle:

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.10' // <= expected version is 1.6.0
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


I'm not really sure where to go from here or what to try. Any help would be AMAZING thank you so much!
I was trying to run my app on an android emulator. I have removed the .gradle files at both the project and user level, ran flutter clean/pub get/build apk several times. I have also tried editing the path, and specifying the path in multiple different ways, I cannot seem to get anything to work - chatGPT has also been no help
